# How can I set background image of button to left-align?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the background image appear near the left border of the button?

```css
.button1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('nebifat.png') no-repeat;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 64px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-style: none;
  height: 7%;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 10%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <button id='r1' class='button1'>Matematica si Fizica</button>
</center>
```

Comment: use `background-position:left center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `no-repeat` in `background-image`, instead you can use `background: url('...') no-repeat` or `background-repeat: no-repeat`, also [`center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) has been removed from the Web standards. And you can position background with [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

```css
.button1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 64px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-style: none;
  height: 7%;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 10%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<button id='r1' class='button1'>Matematica si Fizica</button>
```